# Auth0 rules doesn't add the property in the response

Tags: auth0, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I have some issues adding new properties to **Auth0** response. 
I have defined a new **rule** to add user.awsRole to user object as follows:

```js
function (user, context, callback) {

  user.awsRole = 'arn:aws:iam::951887872838:role/TestSAML,arn:aws:iam::951887872838:saml-provider/MyAuth0';
  user.awsRoleSession = user.name;

  context.samlConfiguration.mappings = {
    'https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/Role': 'awsRole',
    'https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/RoleSessionName': 'awsRoleSession'
  };

  callback(null, user, context);

}
```

when I test, I can see the result which are correct:

```js
The profile is: 
{
  "name": "jdoe@foobar.com",
  "email": "jdoe@foobar.com",
  "nickname": "jdoe",
  "picture": "http://foobar.com/pictures/jdoe.png",
  "awsRole": "arn:aws:iam::951887872838:role/TestSAML,arn:aws:iam::951887872838:saml-provider/MyAuth0",
  "awsRoleSession": "jdoe@foobar.com",
  "user_id": "auth0|0123456789",
  "identities": [
    {
      "provider": "auth0",
      "user_id": "0123456789",
      "connection": "Username-Password-Connection",
      "isSocial": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Now when I try to login using my application, I cannot see the new attribute **awsRole**.

In order to see if the rule is working, I tried to change some of the default attributes, like:

user.email = "Something"

I could see in my application that the email is set to something.

If you know how can I add these custom attributes to the response please let me know.

I am setting up SSO to AWS using Auth0.